# Errors installing RVM

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm, redhat

I'm trying to install rvm on redhat 5.5 and I'm getting this error:

```
[mc@owl-ci ~]$ bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   979  100   979    0     0   8168      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  318k
Cloning into rvm...
remote: Counting objects: 18463, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4985/4985), done.
remote: Total 18463 (delta 12517), reused 17903 (delta 12002)
Receiving objects: 100% (18463/18463), 3.19 MiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12517/12517), done.
mkdir: cannot create directory `/archives': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/src': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/log': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/gems': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/man': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/rubies': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/config': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory `/user': Permission denied
```

I've install rvm before on different machines with no problems.

I'm confused on why it's trying to create directories under the root path, I thought everything went under ~/.rvm (therefore shouldn't have problems with permission)

Comment: Maybe you have a ~/.rvmrc or /etc/rvmrc that sets $rvm_path? (that's what I could figure from the install script)

Comment: It's the install script that's failing (it runs the install script from the bottom of the rvm-install-head script)

Comment: True. I haven't ever used rvm but i tried installing. I get the same errors and some more after that, but in the end I get an installation in ~/.rvm -- well, at least there's something in there. I guess you should report a bug, it can't be normal to get errors during an install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so apparently my old answer wouldn't actually give you a functioning rvm installation.  There appears to be a very recent bug that I will report.  In the meantime, follow the instructions here:

http://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Under the section "Installing / updating the latest rvm from the latest source tarball"

Old Answer:

Try downloading the rvm install script:
curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head > rvm-install-head

Then find the line:
rvm_path="${rvm_path:-"$HOME/.rvm"}"

and add "export" in the front:
export rvm_path="${rvm_path:-"$HOME/.rvm"}"

Save and run the modified file:
bash < rvm-install-head

Comment: The old answer got me farther than before and looked to work. But yes, it didn't give me a functioning rvm install. I'll look into those instructions. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: New answer works with one gotcha: the post-install message says to place
    [[ -s "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
at the bottom of bash profile but $rvm_path isn't defined, so this is the correct one (which is on the website instructions):
    [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

Answer (score 8):

Only use RVM 1.5.1+ or latest head.

You may now install as user or root. Do not use the system-wide script any longer.

bash < <( curl -s -k https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm )

For the most recent information and best practices on the correct way to install RVM, please read the [documentation website](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install). Also be sure to read the [RVM basics documentation](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/basics).

~Wayne

Comment: Welcome Wayne, haven't seen you on here before, but your presence and knowledge will be a great asset to the site. There's a lot of RVM questions, and new users who can gain from your knowledge! RVM rocks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 1.3.0 is broken for the moment.  Checkout 1.2.9 in ~/.rvm/src/rvm for a working version.