# Installing Rubies in system wide RVM 1.5.2 install problem

Tags: installation, rvm

Following [this advice for installing RVM 1.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412589/errors-installing-rvm/5414184#5414184), I used these commands to install RVM 1.5.2 system wide (into /usr/local/rvm):

```
curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head > rvm-install-head
sudo bash rvm-install-head
```

That, in itself, worked.  I added the appropriate source statements in my .bashrc file:

```
[[ -s "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

and proceeded to attempt to install Ruby 1.9.2 with this command:

```
sudo rvm install 1.9.2-head
```

However, I get "rvm: command not found".   If I try it without sudo, I don't have appropriate permissions to create the necessary directories and so forth, as would be expected.  The problem seems to be that the shell function rvm is defined for my user, but when running sudo, it doesn't seem to be available.

My question: What is the correct way to install rubies in a system wide RVM 1.5.2 install?

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the install scripts have been updated to correct this, so it doesn't appear to be an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you have existing provisioning scripts that depend on the old system-wide install script, then staying at RVM version 1.3.0 is another option to consider.

(See [RVM system-wide install script url broken -- what is replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421800/rvm-system-wide-install-script-url-broken-what-is-replacement))

Comment: While true and useful, I'd rather move forward now with 1.5 if I can find the right way forward.